# Firebase Realtime compound queries

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

How can I approach a compound query?

I want to get the values where `Lamp=id AND AssignedTo=''`

So I thought of an approach like this

```
FirebaseDatabase().reference().child('history').orderByChild('Lamp').equalTo(id).orderByChild('AssignedTo').equalTo('');
```

But it did not work.

I am using flutter

Comment: It might be possible if set up an index on the firebase side of things. Not entire sure it will the fix you need though.

Comment: you can't query in firebase's real-time database. you have to use firestore. alternative solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/26701282/8822337

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. In your case that could be `"Lamp_AssignedTo": "idOfLamp_idOfAssignee"`, and you'd then order/filter on that. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase